# Altium - How do I place my GND vias?

Tags: ground, altium, via

I have a 4 layer design, Top, layer2, layer3, bottom.
Now I want to place GND vias on a ground polygon. Layers Top and Bottom both are a complete ground plane (Polygon)

**I was wondering; What is the most effective way to place this GND via and what are the differences?**

I realise that on the first picture, the GND via is connected to the top layer polygon. And on the second picture it is both connected to the Bottom and Top layer polygon.

[image]

FYI, looking at the Eagle design the GND vias are not ''repoured'' as they are on Altium.

[image]

Again, I am nog experienced with Altium. Maybe there is a setting which lets me place these GND vias as they are on Eagle. (If that is a correct method)

Comment: I'm curious - do you have a reason for having ground on top and bottom ? Usually ground is placed as one of the inner layers.

Comment: Are you talking about the thermals? The altium vias have thermal relief. The eagle vias seem to have no thermal relief.

Comment: I am a intern trying to understand the design, and redesigning it as I migrate it from Eagle to Altium.

Comment: @mkeith If I understand correctly, the vias in Eagle are ''Direct Connect'' and the vias in Altium I am placing are ''Relief Connect''

Comment: Right. Is that what you were most curious about? The fact that the Altium vias have voided copper areas around them? I think efox29 explained that well.

Comment: @mkeith Yes he did and that helped me allot. Still I am wondering what type of via connection I should be using in this design. As I said, on another design I have used the ''Relief connect'' while in Ealge it seems that Direct connect is used. This could be a error in that other design. Or it just has to be that way. (Relief connect) So for now I will be placing vias with the relief connect method. And later I will confirm this to my project leader.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You place a via and assign it to the ground net. That's it.

If you are lazy, like me sometimes, I sometimes place the via directly on the net I want the via to be - this can be another trace, polygon, even a pad (and then move it later) - and Altium will automatically assign the via's net to whatever net you placed the via on.

You should probably change your rules so that vias don't add thermal reliefs. You'd want direct connect (unless you plan on soldering things to it).

Create a rule similar to the image below, and that will make all your vias direct connect.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question, now what exactly is the difference between Relief connect and Direct connect? (Currently my rule are set to Relief connect.)

Comment: Thermal reliefs are "special" way of connecting a via to a large copper body (like a plane or polygon pour). Copper is a good heat conductor, so it makes soldering very difficult because the pour or plane acts as a heatsink. If more information is required - this should be posted as a new question (if it hasnt already been answered already).

Comment: I know that on another design there was a separate layer used as ground polygon. And on this layer the via connect style was relief connect. So now I am not sure what style to use. Although, I can always use one style. Then when it is incorrect, I can change to the other style without having to replace all the vias. So I quess I am just going to place all GND vias using the ''Direct Connect'' style.

Comment: Most of the time, vias don't need thermal relief for electrical purposes. But through-hole pins do need thermal relief, otherwise they will be difficult to solder. The problem is that the soldering iron will be trying to heat the entire plane. The thermal relief makes a very noticeable difference in that case. Some SMT components have a large thermal pad in the middle of the component. The pad is part of the GND net. Normally the datasheet says to put lots of vias in the pad. Those vias are for heat conduction purposes, and should NOT have thermal relief. Those vias should be direct connect.